# getting TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting when try to insert data into mysql using python

Tags: python, mysql

I am creating BMI calculator using python `tkinter` gui and MySQL as a backend.

I am getting above error when I try to insert data in bmi table. there are total 7 columns in bmi table.

- 1st col --> pid int pk auto_increment
- 2nd col --> name varchar(20)
- 3rd col --> age tinyint
- 4th col -->phone int
- 5th col --> gender enum('m','f')
- 6th col --> bmi decimal(4,2)
- 7th col -- > date varchar(20)

I tried lot of ways to solve this error and come up here. Please help !

```py
def cal():
    try:
        db = p.Connect(user="root", host="localhost", password="abc123", database="db_shubham")
        x = d.date.today()
        name = cal_window_ent_name.get()
        age = cal_window_ent_age.get()
        phone = cal_window_ent_phone.get()
        h = float(cal_window_ent_height.get())
        w = float(cal_window_ent_weight.get())

        if ge.get() == 1:
            gen = 'm'
        else:
            gen = 'f'

        print(gen)
        bm = w / (h * h)
        t = (None, name, age, phone, gen, bm, x) # getting error here
        sql = "insert into bmi(pid,name,age,gender,bmi,date) values(IFNULL(%s, DEFAULT(pid)),%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
        cr = db.cursor()
        cr.execute(sql,t)
        db.commit()
        showinfo("record added")
    except Exception as e:
        db.rollback()
        print("issue",e)
    finally:
        db.close()
```

Comment: 1. How many items are there in the tuple `t`?  2. How many placeholders are there in the SQL template?

Comment: You say there is a 4th column for phone, but you are not inserting into that 4th column, you omitted the phone column. Or in other words `len(t) != len(columns)`, but it should be same....